# Site redirects with https but works with http on Apache2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, apache2

I have an admin panel at that is acting funky

When the site is preceeded with http:// it *appears to work fine*, however when I use the SSL cert, it is redirecting to the main site with https:// but not the admin panel sub domain. What is also strange is that my api is also coming in as non-secure.

I imagine it has something to do with the way the SSL cert was installed, but I have limited knowledge with apache2.

Here's the admin panel's file in sites-enabled:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName (admin panel url)
ServerAlias (admin panel url)
DocumentRoot (location of admin panel files)

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile (location of ssl crt file)
SSLCertificateKeyFile (location of ssl key file)
SSLCertificateChainFile (location of ssl bundle crt file)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue for my https:// vs http:// problem with the admin panel.
It turns out my virtual hosts were not set up correctly in the admin panel file in /sites-enabled/

I renamed the port for the virtual host for my admin panel and created a new virtual host to catch when users don't go to the secure site and force them into it.

Now it looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName (admin panel url)
    ServerAlias (admin panel url)
    Redirect permanent / https://(admin panel url)
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName (admin panel url)
    ServerAlias (admin panel url)
    DocumentRoot (directory of admin panel files)

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile (location of crt file)
    SSLCertificateKeyFile (location of key file)
    SSLCertificateChainFile (location of bundle crt file)
</VirtualHost>
```